# How to create an array of arrays in UITableviews

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have two tableViewControllers, my first tableView contains a list of items called folders, on click of which I will open the another tableView called ItemsInfolder and display if they are present or else it will empty.

So for this I know that ItemsInFolder View should be an array of arrays, with each array at index position (row position) , but I am confused, on how to do it , how to call array present at each index on click of each folder.

updated according to comments below

```
//FolderTableView
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
   ItemsTableViewController *selectedFolder = [[ItemsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemsTableViewController" bundle:nil];    


    selectedFolder.selectedfolder = [indexPath row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectedFolder animated:YES];


}

//ItemsTableView

-(void)xyz operation
{

[m_ItemArray addObject:item];
[appDelegate.2dArray addObject: m_ItemArray];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [[appDelegate.2dArray objectAtIndex:m_selectedfolder]count];(selected folder index coming from, folderTable)
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *testArray = [appDelegate.2dArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    tableCell.items.text = [testArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];       

    return tableCell;
}
```

So friends, please help me out.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Have you already created the array of arrays to work with ?

Comment: Hi @A-Live thanks for reply, I am confused with it. Can u help me out

Comment: You can add array to another array just like any other object, make sure you initialize `NSMutableArray` if you want to use `addObject` as you can set `NSArray` items only at initialization (you can do it if that's possible to get all the data together)

Comment: You mean this way, NSMutablearray *mainArray; NSMutablearray *itemsArray;, now u say that first I have to add the itmes into the itemsArray and then add this itemArray into mainArray right?.

Comment: That's correct, and you can do it both ways a) prepare the child arrays and add them to the main array b) prepare the main array adding the necessary amount of empty child arrays, get them one by one and fill with items. Just think of array as of general object, you can add it to another array anytime and you can call it's methods from within the holder array anytime.

Comment: @A-Live, Ok, but I have an issue, I did that, now when I click on any of the folders, I get the same items,in each folder, how to resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Considered a `arrayOfFolders` global and initialized, full of arrays containing your files, following this hierarchy :

```
arrayOfFolders :
{
   [0]            //Folder 0 (NSArray)
   {
      file1
      file2
      file3
   }
   [1]            //Folder 1 (NSArray)
   {
      file4
      file5
   }
}
```

When you'll click on your folder inside your tableView, get the child array like that :

```
-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //To retrieve your array within your array at the seleted index
    NSArray * arrayOfItemsInFolder = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.arrayOfFolders objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] copyItems:YES];
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Does this seems right to you?

Comment: Hi @Big00d didnt get you, because my arrayofFolders is 1D array and arrayofItems is 2D array.

Comment: @Ranjit Do you have the names at `arrayofFolders` and `arrayofItems` used to bind them to the items ? if so, just replace `arrayofItems` with `arrayofItems` in the snippet above.

Comment: Your arrayOfFolders is meant to nest arrayOfItems in my example. I'll edit my answer to show you the struct

Comment: Hey @Big00d, i am using ur code in didselectrow, but what is happening is that the items present in folder 1 is only shown in all folders

Comment: I don't get it, could you include your actual didSelectRow's code in your initial question, and the init of your arrays?

Comment: @Ranjit We'll be more able to help you if we could see your code

Comment: @Ranjit if you do display the folder at separate sections you'll want to use `indexPath.section` at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as the row will always be `1` and the section number will show you the folder index at the array.